# The Requested Resource does not support http mehod "Put"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I can GET just fine via /api/set/id or /api/set/archived/, but PUT isn't working.  My routes:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SetId",
            routeTemplate: "api/set/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Set", action = "getset" }
        ); 

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Set",
            routeTemplate: "api/set/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Set", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Set Controller:

```
        [HttpPut]
        [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
        [ActionName("update")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutSet(Set set)
        {
         ...
        }
```

In fiddler I'm PUTting the raw object from a corresponding GET request to:

```
http://localhost:24144/api/set/update
```

But I get

> "{"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http
>   method 'PUT'."}"

Why isn't PUT working?

EDIT: I also tried updating that first route to have an id as optional, and removed the action name on the PUT method.  Then I tried accessing via PUT /api/set and I get the same 405 error - PUT unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the verbs are not registered properly in the web.config?

```
    <authorization>
        <!-- General application authorization -->
        <allow verbs="GET" users="*"/>
        <allow verbs="PUT" users="*"/>
        <allow verbs="POST" users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: Just tried this (these weren't specified originally) - didn't seem to work.  Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 1):

Move this route to the top of your route configuration file:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Set",
            routeTemplate: "api/set/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Set", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and rename your Put Method to Update

[HttpPut]

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Update(Set set)
    {
     ...
    }
```